# Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm having trouble with an an angular error message that i'm trying to work with. I am trying to ensure that a case insensitivity of a confirmation email does not apply to the initial email address.

In my controller I was using the `toLowerCase()` filter....except for the fact that the console does not recognize this and is giving me an error message.

My front end code is

```
input-md{ type: "email", "ng-model" => "vm.form.email_confirmation", required: true, 'must-match' => 'register_form["vm-form-email"]', 'match-case-insensitive' => true, 'ng-hide' => 'vm.form.validated_email', autocapitalize: 'off' }
```

and my controller, (and ultimately where the problem is)

```
getMatchValue = ->
  match = matchGetter($scope)
  if (angular.isObject(match) and match.hasOwnProperty('$viewValue'))
    match = match.$viewValue
  match

$scope.$watch getMatchValue, ->
  ctrl.$$parseAndValidate()
  return

ctrl.$validators.mustMatch = ->
  match = getMatchValue()

  if $attrs.matchCaseInsensitive
    ctrl.$viewValue.toLowerCase() is match.toLowerCase()
  else
    ctrl.$viewValue is match
return
```

If anybody could take a look at this, i would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure your object is not `undefined` you can use [angular.isDefined](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isDefined).

Make sure your objects will not be `undefined`

```
if (angular.isDefined(ctrl.$viewValue)){
    //Your Code
}
```

Comment: I do know that the objects are defined as i've they do work if i create email submissions that have identical case values, everything works out fine. However it is the filters on the objects that it has been having problems with.